# Android Studio onBackPressed() needs to change base class variables

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, back

I have a global navigation bar currently and it works beautifully unless the user hits the back button. I have overridden the back button like so

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        navBar.curr_position = navBar.position.pop();
        Log.d("Backing To pos", Integer.toString(navBar.curr_position));
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(navBar.curr_position, true);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Where `navBar.curr_position` is the `protected static int` containing current position of the activity, and `navBar.position` is a `protected static ArrayDeque` (or stack) from my understanding.

All activities extend my base `navBar` class.
Now what I want the app to do, is when back is called to change the `navBar`'s selection to whatever it was before. However it seems that with Android, when back is called it does not rerun any of the activity or base code so it simply never changes the selection.
Is there a function somewhere that can check to see if the program was just returned to from back and then change the navbar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I can put the setItemChecked code in onStart();